# Why is promise from fetch not resolving (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, fetch

I am new to promises and async/await in react. I have been reading but still, I don't understand why the promise from my `getDate()` method doesn't resolve.

I have been tying many solutions but it all ends the same, with an unresolved promise. Here is the code I'm using.

```
async getData() {
  await this.syncLedgerSum(
    "http://localhost:5000/webapi/getorders"
  ).then(response => this.setState({ items: response }));

  //this works, state.items is displayed on browser console
  //console.log("State Items in getData is : ", this.state.items);
  return this.state.items;
}

async syncLedgerSum(URL) {
  const response = await fetch(URL, {
    method: "GET"
  });
  console.log("syncLedgerSum Response: ", response);

  const json = await response.json();
  console.log("syncLedgerSum json: ", json);
  return json;
}

async componentDidMount() {
    console.log("Component Did mount: ");
    let data = await this.getData();
    if (data) console.log("Items in Component Did mount is : ", data);
}
```

The image above shows the logs from the code I'm using.

### [image]

I don't know why the request doesn't finish. How can I store the data into `state.items` to render that information?

Comment: Your `getData` function doesn't `return` anything, so `data` is always falsy and the if block will never run. The request finishes just fine.

Comment: @Bergi I added  `return this.state.items; ` on `getData()` and still has the same result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Then no, I can't see why you could log it but the returned value is not available in `componentDidMount`. Btw, you really shouldn't call `setState` and then immediately read the value, you should just `await` the response and access that. Then call `setState` at the end of your chain.

Answer (score 0):

Because of how you're handling the response. See a working [codepen](https://codepen.io/caiaoricci/pen/QWwKyqV?editors=1112).

With await you don't have to use `.then` to handle the promise response.

```
async getData() {
  const response = await this.syncLedgerSum(
    "http://localhost:5000/webapi/getorders"
  )

  this.setState({ items: response })
  //this is not a sync call, so you can either await or use the response instead but setState should trigger another render. not sure what you need this for. 

  return response;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you can install [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) with `npm install axios` or `yarn add axios`

> ```
>  getData() {      
>    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/webapi/getorders")
>    .then(function (response) {
>      console.log(response)
>      this.setState({ items: response })
>    })
>    .catch(function (error) {
>       console.log(error)
>      this.setState({ items: [] })
>    })
> }
> ```

in `componentDidMount` you call the function `getData()`

Comment: I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined` in `this.setState({ items: response })`

Comment: installing `axios` does not have anything to do with this error, it can be done using `fetch` itself

Comment: create a constructor in your class and initialize your state